# Traverse nested JSON and assign to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, parsing

Related to my [question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61828984/format-ajax-response-into-html) I have looked into JSON and decided to take it up. The backend creates a json-response of following structure (from console log):

```
{…}
​
    3: {…}
​​
        0: Object { probe_id: "4", date: "19.01.2021", start_time: "13:30", … }
​​
        1: Object { probe_id: "5", date: "20.01.2021", start_time: "13:30", … }
​​
        week_end: "24.01.2021"
​​
        week_start: "18.01."

    4: {…}
​​
        0: Object { probe_id: "6", date: "25.01.2021", start_time: "13:30", … }
​​
        week_end: "31.01.2021"
​​
        week_start: "25.01."
```

I basically need to display the data as in the response. One header object (= Object `3` / `4`) that displays every object it contains. Every data element will get a html wrapper with jquery. So i need to know on which level the object is to set the appropriate wrapper. I've literally been driven insane during the last 3 hours. So how can I traverse the JSON and every nested element?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, but it seems you want to traverse through the object items and apply changes accordingly. You can do this with `recursion`.

```js
var data = {0:{0:{ probe_id: "4", date: "19.01.2021", start_time: "13:30"},1:{ probe_id: "3", date: "19.01.2021", start_time: "13:30"}},1:{0:{ probe_id: "6", date: "25.01.2021", start_time: "13:30" }, week_end: "31.01.2021", week_start: "25.01." }};

traverse = (obj) => {
 for(const property in obj){
  if(typeof obj[property] == 'object'){
   traverse(obj[property]);
   } else { 
   console.log(`Value is ${obj[property]}`);
   //perform some actions here accordingly
   }
 }
}

traverse(data);
```